# Using derived table in subqueries in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these relations:

```
COURSE(COURSEID,SUBJECT)
LESSON(COUSEID,PRESENTSTUDENTS,DATE)
```

I have to select COURSEID that have the maximum average of present students during lessons
I try with:

```
SELECT COURSEINFO.AVERAGESTUDENTS
    FROM (SELECT COURSE.COURSEID,AVG(PRESENTSTUDENTS) AVERAGESTUDENTS
            FROM LESSON,COURSE
          WHERE LESSON.COURSEID=COURSE.COURSEID
          GROUP BY COURSE.COURSEID) COURSEINFO
WHERE COURSEINFO.AVERAGESTUDENTS = (SELECT MAX(M.AVERAGESTUDENTS) 
                                       FROM COURSEINFO M) /*(1)*/
```

But SQL Developer tells me that `COURSEINFO` does not exist in the point where i commented with (1). My question is that: can I use the table that I derived in the external query in the FROM clause (`COURSEINFO`) where I commented? What are the visibility limits of the derived tables? Is there a concept of 'scope' ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you are doing is get max average.

This should do:

```
select max(avg(presentstudents))
from lesson l
join course c on l.courseid = c.courseid
group by c.courseid
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved it. But I still have no idea where the error is in my first attempt and because that table is not visible at that point

Comment: @SalvoNice you can't use a subquery defined in the from clause for selection again (use CTE for this). But your problem didnt need it.

Answer (score 0):

Gurwinder's answer is one solution, as would be a solution using `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` or analytic functions.  All those answers are "better" in the sense that they are more concise and produce better execution plans.

But given your constraints, use a CTE not a subquery:

```
WITH COURSEINFO AS (
      SELECT C.COURSEID, AVG(L.PRESENTSTUDENTS) as AVERAGESTUDENTS
      FROM LESSON L JOIN
           COURSE C
           ON L.COURSEID = C.COURSEID
      GROUP BY C.COURSEID
     )
SELECT ci.AVERAGESTUDENTS
FROM COURSEINFO ci
WHERE ci.AVERAGESTUDENTS = (SELECT MAX(M.AVERAGESTUDENTS) 
                            FROM COURSEINFO ci2
                           ) ;
```

Also, promise never to use commas in the `FROM`.  Don't learn bad syntax when you are learning SQL.

Answer (score 0):

COURSEINFO here is not a table, rather an alias given to the subquery

```
(SELECT COURSE.COURSEID,AVG(PRESENTSTUDENTS) AVERAGESTUDENTS
            FROM LESSON,COURSE WHERE LESSON.COURSEID=COURSE.COURSEID
          GROUP BY COURSE.COURSEID)
```

For your query, the other subquery

```
(SELECT MAX(M.AVERAGESTUDENTS) FROM COURSEINFO M)
```

may be executed first by the compiler and it will throw the error since there is no such table as COURSEINFO.